# syntax error near unexpected token `newline' for my nnoremap in .vimrc?

Tags: vim

Here is the configuration of my .vimrc.

[image]

For the 12 th line.

```
nnoremap <F12> :!/opt/google/chrome/chrome '%:p'<CR>

source .vimrc
bash: /home/debian9/.vimrc: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: /home/debian9/.vimrc: line 12: `nnoremap <F12> :!/opt/google/chrome/chrome '%:p'<CR>'
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `source` in your Bash shell; the right command is `:source .vimrc` **inside Vim**!

Please note that reloading your Vim configuration may work, or not (depending what you do, how you define `:autocmd`s, whether the changed configuration affects already loaded plugins). If in doubt, it's easier to just `:quit` Vim and restart it; the new `.vimrc` will then be loaded automatically.

The syntax of your Vim configuration in `~/.vimrc` is *Vimscript*; this is only understood by Vim itself. Your shell configuration would be put in (for example) `~/.bashrc`; you can `source` that in your shell.